# How do I correctly initialise a property of type storage task in a kotlin class

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-storage

I have initialised a field called mUploadsTask and it is of type StorageTask.
The class `StorageTask` has been imported but I am still getting an error on Android Studio.
The error says: "One type argument expected for class StorageTask<ResultT : StorageTask.ProvideError!>"
My guess is that there is an argument I am supposed to put in the class but I do not know what that is.

Here is the line of code I had written:

```kotlin
lateinit var mUploadsTask: StorageTask
```

Please any suggestions would be fine thank you!

I had tried rewriting it as

```kotlin
lateinit var mUploadsTask: StorageTask.ProvideError
```

this still gave an error on android studio as I could not access the private provideerrror inside the `StorageTask` class.

After this I tried

```kotlin
lateinit var mUploadsTask: StorageTask()
```

then

```kotlin
lateinit var mUploadsTask: StorageTask(ResultT)
```

then

```kotlin
lateinit var mUploadsTask: StorageTask<ResultT>
```

and then

```kotlin
lateinit var mUploadsTask: StorageTask(ProvideError)
```

and all of this still lead to errors
i then tried

```kotlin
 lateinit var mUploadsTask: StorageTask<ResultT : StorageTask.ProvideError!>
```

and Android Studio gave me an error telling me `ResultT` is an unresolved reference

Comment: You need to read and understand what generics are in the Kotlin documentation. You might want to read the official Java documentation about generics first even if you don’t know Java, because it explains the basics of generics much more clearly. After your grasp the concept of generics, then if you still have trouble understanding the class above, you could ask about it here.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is an upload task, you can use `UploadTask` which extends from `StorageTask`, as seen in the [ref docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/kotlin/com/google/firebase/storage/UploadTask):

```kotlin
lateinit var mUploadTasks: UploadTask
```

The Firebase Android SDK is Open Source, which means you can check the [source code](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk) - you'll notice that the [`UploadTask` implementation](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/blob/7b7a6b174f6a9a7ec4ae58717f374beb18fd4172/firebase-storage/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/storage/UploadTask.java#L58) extends `StorageTask` with a Result type (which in turn extends from `StorageTask.ProvideError`) as argument (in this case `UploadTask.TaskSnapshot`):

```java
public class UploadTask extends StorageTask<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> {
```